# Jersey Web Service ExceptionMapper Oracle EPM HFMException

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0, exceptionmapper

I have created a Web Service ( running on Tomcat Server ) using one of the standard Oracle EPM Java API's for extracting HFM metadata. When there is an error within the API's it throws a HFM Exception which is a subclass of java Exception class. I would like to capture the error before it gets to the Tomcat server and be able to display the proper message from HFM. I have created a ExceptionMapper for the HFMException, but that did not capture the error. I have checked the WEB.XML to make sure that package where the ExceptionMapper has been  created is in the  and that looks OK.

**Below is the initial HFM error:** Error from Tomcat server (Eclipse)

[image: Screen Shot]

This is the ExceptionMapper that I have created to handle the HFM Exception (I have also created one for the RegistryException)

**HFMExceptionMapper Class**

[image: Screen Shot].

What else is needed to get the ExceptionMapper to work.

Thanks

[Web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBRk4.png)

I've rewritten the Web Service using ResourceConfig so avoiding using WEB.XML. I have created ExceptionMapper classes for the following 3rd Party Exceptions from HFM ( HFMException / RegistryException ) and also created a GeneralExceptionMapper. I have registered the classes in my ResourceConfig class and now the GeneralExceptionMapper is working but none of the more specific HFM based Excpetions.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? And can you post your web.xml?

Comment: Hi Paul - the exception is being thrown when creating an instance of the HFM Security class

Comment: Security security = new Security();
Following error occurs
INFO: EPMREG-11070 com.hyperion.hit.registry.exceptions.RegistryException <init>
Then the following exception occurs
 SEVERE:EPMHFM-65536
oracle.epm.fm.common.exception.HFMException.
Web XML
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>org.epm.hfm.HfmFileScan;
  org.epm.hfm.Exception</param-value>
  </init-param>  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
 <param-value>
        org.epm.hfm.HfmFileScan.HFMExceptionMapper </param-value>
 </init-param>

Comment: is there any sample projects like this?